# Kubectl: command not found on travis ci

Tags: docker, kubernetes, travis-ci, gcloud

I am trying to deploy a kubernetes cluster using Travis CI and I get the following error

EDIT:

> invalid argument "myAcc/imgName:" for t: invalid reference format
>
> See docker build --help
>
> ./deploy.sh: line 1: kubectl: command not found

This is my travis config file

`travis.yml`

```
sudo: required
services: 
  - docker
env:
  global:
    - SHA-$(git rev-parse HEAD)
    - CLOUDSDK_CORE_DISABLE_PROMPTS=1
before-install:
  - openssl aes-256-cbc -K $encrypted_0c35eebf403c_key -iv $encrypted_0c35eebf403c_iv -in service-account.json.enc -out service-account.json -d
  - curl https://sdk.cloud.google.com | bash > /dev/null
  - source $HOME/google-cloud-sdk/path.bash.inc
  - gcloud components update kubectl
  - gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file service-account.json
  - gcloud config set project robust-chess-234104
  - gcloud config set compute/zone asia-south1-a
  - gcloud container clusters get-credentials standard-cluster-1
  - echo "$DOCKER_PASSWORD" | docker login -u "$DOCKER_USERNAME" --password-stdin

deploy:
  provider: script
  script: bash ./deploy.sh
  on: 
    branch: master
```

This is my deploy script

`deploy.sh`

```
doccker build -t myAcc/imgName:$SHA
docker push myAcc/imgName:$SHA
kubectl apply -k8s
```

I guess the `gcloud components update kubectl` command is not working. Any ideas?

Thanks !

Comment: how did you install kubectl anyway ? I cannot see it in your yml file

Comment: It's in the 4th line under before-install. `gcloud components update kubectl` will install kubectl right?

Comment: this error `invalid argument "myAcc/imgName:" for t: invalid reference format` because `$SHA` is empty

Comment: it should be like this: `- SHA=$(git rev-parse HEAD)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first issue `invalid argument "myAcc/imgName:" for t: invalid reference format` because the variable `$SHA` is not defined as expected. There is a syntax issue with defining the variable you should use `=` instead of `-` after SHA, so it should be like this:

```
- SHA=$(git rev-parse HEAD)
```

The second issue which is related to kubectl you need to install it using the following command according to the [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubectl/#download-as-part-of-the-google-cloud-sdk):

```
gcloud components install kubectl
```

**Update**:

After testing this file on Travis-CI I was able to figure out the issue. You should use `before_install` instead of `before-install` so in your case the before installation steps never get executed.

```
# travis.yml
---
env:
  global:
    - CLOUDSDK_CORE_DISABLE_PROMPTS=1
before_install:
 - curl https://sdk.cloud.google.com | bash > /dev/null
 - source $HOME/google-cloud-sdk/path.bash.inc
 - gcloud components install kubectl

script: kubectl version
```

And the final part of the build result:

```
$ kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"11", GitVersion:"v1.11.7", GitCommit:"65ecaf0671341311ce6aea0edab46ee69f65d59e", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-01-24T19:32:00Z", GoVersion:"go1.10.7", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

Comment: Thanks mate. The docker typo is fixed. And I added `gcloud components install kubectl` in both before install and the deploy.sh file. It still says `/deploy.sh: line 6: kubectl: command not found` :(

Comment: @ShankarThyagarajan I have reviewed my answer again , currently it should be good. are you still having issues regarding this ?

Comment: Yeah, I tried both the methods. But It doesn't seem to work. Shall I ask another question with my updated scripts? This contains the docker typo too, which is kinda off topic

Comment: @ShankarThyagarajan Please check the updated answer and don't forget to mark it as answer

Comment: It worked. Thanks. I think travis could do some error reporting on the yml files!